# Looping through slices of Theano tensor

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, slice, theano

I have two 2D Theano tensors, call them `x_1` and `x_2`, and suppose for the sake of example, both `x_1` and `x_2` have shape (1, 50). Now, to compute their mean squared error, I simply run:

```
    T.sqr(x_1 - x_2).mean(axis = -1).
```

However, what I wanted to do was construct a new tensor that consists of their mean squared error in chunks of 10. In other words, since I'm more familiar with NumPy, what I had in mind was to create the following tensor M in Theano:

```
    M = [theano.tensor.sqr(x_1[:, i:i+10] - x_2[:, i:i+10]).mean(axis = -1) for i in xrange(0, 50, 10)]
```

Now, since Theano doesn't have for loops, but instead uses scan (which map is a special case of), I thought I would try the following:

```
    sequence = T.arange(0, 50, 10)
    M = theano.map(lambda i: theano.tensor.sqr(x_1[:, i:i+10] - x_2[:, i:i+10]).mean(axis = -1), sequence)
```

However, this does not seem to work, as I get the error:

> only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Is there a way to loop through the slices using theano.scan (or map)? Thanks in advance, as I'm new to Theano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what can be done in `numpy`, a solution would be to reshape your (1, 50) tensor to a (1, 10, 5) tensor (or even a (10, 5) tensor), and then to compute the mean along the second axis.

To illustrate this with numpy, suppose I want to compute means by slices of 2

```
x = np.array([0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6])
x = x.reshape([3, 2])
np.mean(x, axis=1)
```

outputs

```
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])
```

Comment: Thanks! that's a whole hell of a lot easier than using scan!